# Front-end to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Tags: configuration, mime-types, xdg-open

SOLVED: Apparently, Xfce does not use `~/.config/mimeapps.list` anyway, because even though `~/.config/mimeapps.list` names Firefox as the default browser, links open in Chromium.

Is there a front-end for `~/.config/mimeapps.list`?  I have tried to change the default browser to Chromium by running:

```
xdg-mime default chromium.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime default chromium.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
```

But `~/.config/mimeapps.list` still mentions Firefox.  This command didn't work either:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium.desktop
```

I have also tried `xfce4-settings-manager` > *Preferred Applications* > *Web Browser* but it didn't work, either.

`chromium.desktop` is at:

```
/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop
/usr/share/xfce4/helpers/chromium.desktop
```

I am running Xfce, in case that matters.

EDIT:

```
xdg-settings get default-web-browser
```

returns `chromium.desktop`.

I have also tried to set Chromium by using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

Comment: I don't have xfce at the moment but you might try editing `~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc` with `WebBrowser=chromium` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, but that file already has `WebBrowser=chromium`.